# Pandas not working in Downloads Directory

Tags: python, macos, pandas

When I enter my `Downloads` directory on Mac OSX (10.9.5), I entered Python from my terminal and tried to import pandas using `import pandas as pd`

```
name:Downloads name$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 30, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "token.py", line 7, in <module>
    reader = csv.reader(open('ebook.csv', 'rb'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ebook.csv'
```

In other directories I've tried though, this seems to import pandas just fine without complaint (including random System directories, the home directory and my ~/Documents directory).

Why is ebook.csv a problem simply in the Downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a file called `token.py` in your Downloads directory.
It is getting imported instead of the `token.py` module from the standard library:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 30, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "token.py", line 7, in <module>
    reader = csv.reader(open('ebook.csv', 'rb'))
```

The solution is to rename the `Downloads/token.py` file so that it does not shadow the standard library module of the same name.

---

Above, the line

```
from token import *
```

tells Python to import the `token` module. Usually, Python would find the `token` module from the standard library, `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/token.py`.

The directory from which you launch Python is inserted as the *first* directory
in `sys.path`. Python searches `sys.path` for modules *in the order* they are
listed.  When you launch Python from the `Downloads` directory, this directory
becomes the first directory searched by Python for modules. So your
`Downloads/token.py` file is getting imported instead of the
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/token.py` (standard library) file.

---

Conclusion: Never name a file the same as any [module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html).

Comment: Thank you! The problem was within the `Downloads` directory, not `Documents`, but your logic and explanation completely applied still, and indeed it turned out I did have a `token.py` in the `Downloads` directory haha